# What event does jQuery provide on multi select list?

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

I am trying to make my multi select list respond to selection by mouse (assuming always one selection). Say I have the following multi select. When the user selects the first value, I would like to show the image in the `<div class="displayimage"> </div>`, however, I am not sure how to trigger the selection event by using jQuery.

```
<div class="controls">
            <select name="images" class="input-xlarge" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="http://localhost/1402974103387.jpg">http://localhost/1402974103387.jpg</option>
                <option value="http://localhost/1402974103891.png">http://localhost/1402974103891.png</option>
                <option value="http://localhost/1402974103212.gif">http://localhost/1402221323231.gif</option>

            </select>
        </div>
<div class="displayimage"> </div>
```

Comment: `$('select').click()`?

Comment: That hasn't much to do with jQuery as there are a lot of standard JS events that should cover that case too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `.click()`:

```
$('select').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).val();
    if ($('.displayimage img').length == 0) {
        $('.displayimage').append($('<img/>'))
    }
    $('.displayimage img').attr('src', src);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xAtV/)

Comment: OP uses `multiple` for the `select` so no menu to be opened. `.change` might still work though.